# Canceling a post.runnable from a lower class

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a runnable that runs five seconds after the main thread is paused.

```
 @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        unixHandler = new Handler();
        Runnable calculateTime = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                calcTime();

            }
        };
```

I want the handler to cancel when onResume() is called.

```
@Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();

        unixHandler.removeCallbacks(calculateTime);

    }
```

Something like this would be great if it worked, but I cant reference the calculateTime runnable because it is defined in another scope. Is there a way to globally define a runnable in order to cancel it from a different method?

Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: "...but I cant reference the calculateTime runnable because it is defined in another scope." - Well, look at how you declared `unixHandler`, and how you have access to it in both methods.

Comment: @MikeM. i declared unixHanler globally, but the onResume method is called before the unixHandler runs so i get an error for canceling a handler that dosent exist.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, but you can instantiate the `Handler` on the declaration line, instead of in `onPause()`.

Comment: @MikeM. when making a handler I declaed the runnable calculateTime. I need to reference calculate time from the onResume class, which i cant do because i dont know of a way to globally declare a runnable

Comment: Move `Runnable calculateTime = new Runnable() {...};` to where you declared `unixHandler`.

Comment: @MikeM. i declared the handler globally but removing he callbacks does not keep it from logging the message inside it. I even tried making a variable called timeCalculabe and set it false in onResume() and true in onCreate() i cant keep the handler from running.

Comment: You need to instantiate the `Handler` on the declaration line, and get rid of the instantiation in `onPause()`, otherwise it's a new one every time `onPause()` runs, and it won't have had that `Runnable` posted to it to remove. - `private Handler unixHandler = new Handler();`. The only thing that should be in `onPause()` is the `postDelayed()` call.